# how to restore the database backup in test server database?

Tags: mysql

i am using mysql database. i am trying to restore the database backup in test server.
my backup file called steer_backup.sql is stored in /root. from the command prompt i am executing the command

```
mysqldump - u root -p steer < steer_backup.sql
```

and i will give the password on asking.
but it does not restore the database. i am not sure whether i am doing some mistakes because this is my first time experience of committing the code to test server ... please help me ..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you created `steer` database on test server? `mysqldump` does not created it for you

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` is use to create a dump.

If you want to restore a sql backup, just use

```
mysql -u [user] -p [databaseName] < [file]
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` is for dumping.  To import, just use `mysql`.

```
mysql -uRoot -pPassword dbname < file.sql
```

Comment: If you're going to downgrade answers, at least give some feedback.  Because this answer and Haza's are both correct.